# SWIFT OS X - multiple statements inside a closure statement, a debugging tool?

Tags: arrays, macos, swift, debugging, closures

I am using the following code to filter a large array:

```
var arrayOfSelectedRowDetails = self.projectRowDetails.filter(
  { $0.projectNumber == self.projectNumberArray[selectedRow] }
)
```

Normally the code runs fine and I have no issues.  But in one scenario (after I have deleted some management objects from the persistent store) and then rerun the code I am getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address=0x0) error at runtime.

I have set a break and stepped through the runtime of this statement.  It is a large array built from a core data entity (using a fetch statement) - and therefore takes a long time.  When I step through the code over the first dozen or so indexes the code runs ok - when i remove the break and let it run it then presents the error.

Is it possible to println() from within the closure statement to assist with debugging?  I have tried a number of different syntaxes and cannot get it to work.

Alternatively, is it possible to set an error capture statement within the closure so that the code ceases through a break or an abort() statement?

Fundamentally i am trying to identify the index of the array at the point that the error occurs so that I can get sufficient information to debug the delete function (which is where I think the error is).  I do not seem to be able to ascertain the index from the info available to me when the error occurs.

This is the first time I have tried programming in Swift and making use of closures so I am learning as I go.  Apologies if I am asking fundamental questions.  I have not been able to find a similar question elsewhere here with an answer that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an exception breakpoint in Xcode (for an example see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html)).

Also, I suggest that you move the access to self.projectNumberArray out of the closure:

```
let pn = self.projectNumberArray[selectedRow] 
var arrayOfSelectedRowDetails = self.projectRowDetails.filter(
   { $0.projectNumber == pn }
)
```

The change might not solve the issue, but it will at least help the debugging.

Lastly, if you want to print the index, the following approach will probably work:

```
let pn = self.projectNumberArray[selectedRow] 
var index = 0
var arrayOfSelectedRowDetails = self.projectRowDetails.filter(
   { println(index++); return $0.projectNumber == pn }
)
```

Comment: Thanks Mario - what I had been missing in particular was the need to use 'return' within the closure syntax with multiple statements - which I guess is implied in a single statement closure.